# BCH to paxful pls help

Tags: altcoin

If can anyone tell me how I can recover my BCH I mistakenly sent to paxful wallet address though I'm still seeing unspent on my BCH wallet I'm so confused pls help

Comment: Could you please tell me more details? "mistakenly sent to paxful wallet address" is that paxful address yours?  - then your BTC is still not lost - It's still in your wallet, do you mean this?

Comment: Yes it's my paxful wallet but paxful support said they don't refund or covert any BCH sent to any paxful wallet... this is my paxful wallet I d. 3MnBe9KoCyh7Wp79ogtmsBDADoL8rjR3Zs

Comment: one biggest attribute of cryptocurrencies is **irreversible**. It's just like you give cash to someone, then unless he gives you back, no 3party can refund it for you. - anyhow refunds or coverts are impossible - But I don't think that's any problem with you, and you're not at any loss - since you've sent your bitcoin to **your own** paxful wallet. Just log into your paxful account, you'll see the money.? Right? If you want to transfer them back, just transfer them back from your paxful! I've been trading bitcoin in paxful for serveral times, paying USD to get BTC, etc.

Comment: I saw 0.52461990 BCH in your paxful wallet you provided. Is that right?

Comment: When I check my paxful wallet I didn't see any coins there the balance is still 0.0Usd that is what is showing me today make it day 4 since I have transferred the BCH into my paxful

Comment: Pls can I have your number maybe you can help me out more better

Comment: Yes I saw 0.52461990 BCH when I track ok blockchain explore but my paxful wallet balance didn't show anything

Comment: Instead with a phone number why not try live chat? I am willing to help you. The first reason I consider is that you may have sent BCH to a BTC address, please take a check?

Comment: Did you clicked “receive Bitcoin” and sent bitcoin cash to the address? Bitcoin and bitcoin cash are different cryptos.

Comment: in my vision i didn’t see bitcoin cash receiving option , I only saw receive bitcoin in paxfu

Comment: Yes I used the BTC address to received BCH that was the mistake

Comment: I’ve just sent a tiny amount to your paxfu see if you can receive (maybe transaction will take some time) but if you received my BTC then it’s solely because you sent BCH to BTC address

Comment: Oh yes I received it

Comment: Definitely the BCH is gone

Comment: I am sorry that this happened to you :(  you’re taught a really expensive lesson for that.. Further when you deal with crypto make sure to check with full caution especially the Currency TyPE when sending any money because the send is irreversible :(.

Comment: Who's now holding the coins is it paxful or Bitcoin.com because i transferred the BCH from my bitcoin.com bch wallet

Comment: Thanks so much next time I will be more careful